# discord.js - Check the DB(decibel) live in a voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, discord.js

I am trying to find the decibel of a user in a voice channel in discord,

```
if (user.decibel > 100) { user.channel.send('you husty pig, shush')}
```

this isn't correct code but its just an example of what I am thinking, To be honest tho I am not sure if it even exists in JavaScript, if you know a way to check decibel of an Mp3 file then I can work with it.

Comment: There is [decibel-meter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decibel-meter) package that you could take a look if you could implement that

Comment: I will try that, I will keep everyone updated if i figure it out